# Есть ли принципиальная разница: ставить или не ставить else, если в if-блоке есть return или throw?

Tags: c++

Допустим, есть следующий код:

```cpp
if (condition)
    return 0;
else
    DoSomething();
```

Его можно переписать как:

```cpp
if (condition)
    return 0;
DoSomething();
```

В обоих случаях при условии, что `condition == true`, будет выполнен возврат из функции, а в противном случае будет вызвана функция `DoSomething()`. Аналогичный пример можно привести с оператором `throw` вместо `return`. То есть логически в этих двух случаях (с `else` и без) разницы не будет абсолютно никакой.

Вопрос: есть ли какие-либо веские причины обязательно ставить или обязательно не ставить `else` в подобных ситуациях? Возможно, есть какие-то, хотя бы незначительные, различия в производительности между приведёнными двумя примерами (с `else` и без)?

Comment: Без разницы, но imho код выглядит лучше, когда букв меньше (т.е. пишите без else)

Comment: https://clang.llvm.org/extra/clang-tidy/checks/readability-else-after-return.html

Comment: Основная проблема не сам else, а лишний отступ, увеличивающий когнитивную сложность.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Основная разница должна быть в семантике и том, что должен понять тот, кто будет читать этот код в будущем. **Все зависит от окружающего кода и вкладываемого смысла.**

Если этот код записан в функции из 3 строчек и больше внутри ничего нет, то никакой особой разницы нет. Если же это функция из 5+ строк, то семантика уже проявляется (и зависит от вложенности и расположения фрагмента). Ниже речь об этом:

---

```
if A then return 0 else B;
```

Так скорее выглядит код внутри цикла, когда (не)найдено некоторое искомое значение и этого достаточно для определения результата функции. Или какой-то вызов метода создания/инициализации чего-либо.

---

```
if A then return 0;
```

Так обычно выглядят guard-statements / early-exit statements - условия проверяемые в самом начале функции, когда заранее можно определить конечный результат не выполняя основное тело функции.

---

Касательно Return или это Throw - не принципиально. В случае Return мы определяем "хороший" выход, а в случае Throw - "плохой".

Comment: Не вижу глубокого смысла в `if A then return 0 else B;`

Comment: @avp это вам у ТС надо поинтересоваться. Все зависит от контекста.

Comment: TC как раз об этом спрашивает. На мой взгляд, ни от какого контекста не зависит. Если только платят по доллару за каждую букву в коде

Comment: @avp вангуйте пожалуйста, фрагмент кода содержится в функции из этих 2-3 строчек, или в 150-строчной простынке? Дополнил ответ, спасибо за наводку на мысль.

Comment: @avp утрируем, а что скажете про `if A then return 0 else throw;`? )

Comment: То же самое. Но я бы предпочел `if (!A) throw; return 0;` Т.е. акцентировать внимание на исключении (хотя, использование стиля программирования с exceptions само по себе  вызывает вопросы, но это уже совсем другая тема)

Comment: @avp вынужден несолгаситься, т.к. условия обычно (кроме guard и пару других случаев) принято писать без лишних отрицаний и расчитывая на то что ветка true дефолтная. Т.е. семантика может быть как и "`if CreateFoo return 0 else throw;`"? так и "`if ThrowOnNotImplemented throw; return 0;`"

Comment: Здесь, пожалуй, соглашусь (но все равно без `else`) / `if (CreateFoo) return 0; throw;`

Answer (score -2):

Если  в теле `else` выполняются действия, которые не являются  валидными (например:   "если речь идет только о жидких и твердых объектах и это не  жидкость, то бросим в корзину для мусора"), если не выполняется условие `condition` (допустим оно проверяет является ли объект жидким?). Не выполнив в теле `else`  эти действия, вы по любому выполняете их, но бросить жидкий объект в корзину нельзя, и это приводит к нарушению правил (в частности крушение программы, генерация исключения и т.д.). Написав то же самое в теле `else`, действия вы выполняете при условии, если `condition` не выполняется (не жидкий объект), и нет проблем...

Примером может являться ответ, [следующего](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1211735/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BF-%D1%83-%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2)

вопроса:

```
template<typename ...T>
bool implic(T... args) {
    if  (!(std::is_integral_v<decltype(args)> && ...))
        return false; 
    else    return(args | ...);          
}
```

Если передать в функцию не интегральный тип, то  вернет ложь, а если  убрать  `else` , то специализация не компилируется, если с объектом типа невозможно выполнить битовую операцию. Так что тут  `else` убрать нельзя.

Comment: Что-то запутанно получается. Вы вмешиваете что-то лишнее .. Пример специально минимизирован до одного условия (`condition`) и двух возвратов (`0` или `DoSomething`).

Comment: Здесь ошибка компиляции будет независимо от else. Если бы был `if constexpr`, тогда другое дело.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, а  по какой причине? Вы проверяли?

Comment: Я имел в виду, если передать тип, с которым не работает `|`. Проверил: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/qszYTP

Comment: в msvc не работает независимо от наличия else, в остальных компиляторах работает независимо от наличия else.. С constexpr везде работает без else

Comment: Кажется, понял суть описывамой проблемы. Но всё равно пример кажется синтетичским. Это нужно выносить в концепты.

Comment: Как-то так: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/rfT7dr