# Как посмотреть выведенный тип у вариативных шаблонов?

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++, c++17

Имеется такая функция. Каким образом с помощью decltype или std::decay_t можно узнать тип параметра и использовать его в конструкции if constexpr например? Благодарю.

```
template<typename ...T>
bool implic(T... args) {
    return(args | ...);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
template<typename ...T>
bool implic(T... args) {
    if constexpr (!(std::is_integral_v<decltype(args)> && ...))
        return false;
    else
        return(args | ...);          
}
```

Такой пример подойдет?

Comment: более чем. спасибо<3

Comment: Может и пример плохой, но тут важна суть, а не сам пример. Кто то этого не понял...

Answer (score 4):

Чтобы узнать тип параметра его необходимо извлечь из пачки параметров `T`. Для этого можно воспользоваться кортежами из стандартной библиотеки:

```
#include <tuple>
#include <type_traits>
#include <cstddef>

template< typename ... T >
bool implic(T ... args)
{
    if constexpr
    (
        ::std::is_same_v
        <
            ::std::tuple_element_t< ::std::size_t{2}, ::std::tuple< T ... > >
        ,   int
        >
    )
    {
        // параметр с индексом 2 имеет тип int...
    }
    return (args | ...);
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/hYx4Gn